# CreatedBy.Name returns null in after insert trigger context

Tags: tasks, after-trigger

I got an after insert trigger that runs on the Task object, can someone explain why I'm getting null when trying to retrieve the createdBy.Name?

```
for (Task t: (List < Task > ) Trigger.New) {
    System.debug('Task.createdBy.Name: ' + t.createdBy.Name); // null
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trigger will only contain the field values of the records, not the fields of the referenced records. So in order to get the name of the creator, you will have to query it separately, for example:

```
List<Task> tasksWithCreatorNames = [SELECT Id, CreatedBy.Name FROM Task WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new];
```